# gnome-shell: Error while loading thumbnail

Tags: gnome-shell, thumbnails

I was checking the output from journalctl and I see a large number of the following entries:

> gnome-shell[5944]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat

Seems to be a couple thousand over a short period of time

```
$ uptime; sudo journalctl -b | grep thumbnail | wc -l
 10:37:23 up 19:36,  1 user,  load average: 0.89, 1.06, 1.21
2171
$
```

My thoughts are that there is a thumbnail somewhere that gnome is trying to reference that is corrupt somehow - maybe the thumbnail's width is returning a non float value?

I have tried deleted the following directory: **~/.cache/thumbnails**
It was recreated when I next opened nautilus, navigated to a directory containing pictures and changed views to the "show grid" view.

This made no difference.

How can I identify which thumbnail this is in reference to?

---

Edit 0:

```
$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 4 user user 4096 Mar 23 10:48 .
drwx------ 4 user user 4096 May 28 12:55 ..
drwxrwxr-x 8 user user 4096 Apr 13 10:21 gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io
drwxrwxr-x 4 user user 4096 Mar 11 13:19 system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com
$ 
$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 68
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4096 Nov 28  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Mar 17 15:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 22 08:29 apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 22 08:29 auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 22 08:29 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 22 08:29 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 22 08:29 horizontal-workspaces@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 22 08:29 launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 22 08:29 native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 22 08:29 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 22 08:29 screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Nov 19  2020 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Nov 19  2020 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 22 08:29 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 22 08:29 window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 22 08:29 windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 22 08:29 workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
$
```

output of syslog (I only included the current syslog):
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BmRbpMVK8B/

---

Edit 1:
I have removed gsconnect and system-monitor extensions and rebooted. I have seen a noticable decrease in error messages today:

```
$ sudo grep gnome-shell /var/log/syslog | grep thumbnail
May 31 08:43:52 pc gnome-shell[5787]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
May 31 08:43:52 pc gnome-shell[5787]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
May 31 08:43:52 pc gnome-shell[5787]: message repeated 6 times: [ Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat]
May 31 08:43:53 pc gnome-shell[5787]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
May 31 08:43:53 pc gnome-shell[5787]: message repeated 19 times: [ Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat]
May 31 09:41:45 pc gnome-shell[5787]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
May 31 09:41:45 pc gnome-shell[5787]: message repeated 13 times: [ Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat]
May 31 13:08:12 pc gnome-shell[5787]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
May 31 13:08:13 pc gnome-shell[5787]: message repeated 13 times: [ Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat]
May 31 14:36:49 pc gnome-shell[5787]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
May 31 14:36:49 pc gnome-shell[5787]: message repeated 13 times: [ Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat]
May 31 15:41:26 pc gnome-shell[5787]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
May 31 15:41:36 pc gnome-shell[5787]: message repeated 27 times: [ Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat]
$
```

---

Edit 2:

I now only have the following extensions enabled:

```
$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May 31 16:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Mar 17 15:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 22 08:29 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 19  2020 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 19  2020 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
$
```

```
$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 May 28 17:17 .
drwx------ 4 user user 4096 Jun  1 09:10 ..
$
```

I reinstalled gnome-shell-extension-prefs and libdazzle-1.0-0 and rebooted. The following are the errors since booting:

```
$ uptime; sudo journalctl -b | grep thumbnail
 08:40:00 up 2 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.97, 0.66, 0.26
Jun 01 08:38:03 pc audit[2679]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" pid=2679 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun 01 08:38:35 pc gnome-shell[6136]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
Jun 01 08:38:35 pc gnome-shell[6136]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
Jun 01 08:38:35 pc gnome-shell[6136]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
Jun 01 08:38:35 pc gnome-shell[6136]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
Jun 01 08:38:35 pc gnome-shell[6136]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
Jun 01 08:38:35 pc gnome-shell[6136]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
Jun 01 08:38:35 pc gnome-shell[6136]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
Jun 01 08:38:35 pc gnome-shell[6136]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
Jun 01 08:38:35 pc gnome-shell[6136]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
Jun 01 08:38:35 pc gnome-shell[6136]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
Jun 01 08:38:35 pc gnome-shell[6136]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
Jun 01 08:38:35 pc gnome-shell[6136]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
Jun 01 08:38:35 pc gnome-shell[6136]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
Jun 01 08:38:35 pc gnome-shell[6136]: Error while loading thumbnail: Error: Argument width: value is out of range for gfloat
$
```

---

Edit 3:

Screenshot of upper right corner of desktop:
[image: Screenshot of upper right corner of desktop]

---

Edit 4:

So because I have removed all extensions other than the core ones, and am still receiving thumbnail errors when logging in (i.e. not even having done anything) I deleted all files on my desktop (which did include some images), deleted **~/.local/thumbnails** again and rebooted

There were no errors:

```
$ uptime; sudo journalctl -b | grep thumbnail
 09:50:25 up 35 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.78, 0.64, 0.51
Jun 01 09:15:06 cn-lat7490 audit[2668]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" pid=2668 comm="apparmor_parser"
$
```

But also, there is also no thumbnail directory:

```
$ ls -al ~/.cache/thumbnails/
ls: cannot access '/home/user/.cache/thumbnails/': No such file or directory
$
```

So I navigated to my **Pictures** directory in Nautilus to generate some thumbnails and I still have no errors

```
$ uptime; sudo journalctl -b | grep thumbnail; ls -al ~/.cache/thumbnails
 09:54:04 up 39 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.49, 0.57, 0.51
Jun 01 09:15:06 pc audit[2668]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" pid=2668 comm="apparmor_parser"
total 12
drwx------  3 user user 4096 Jun  1 09:52 .
drwx------ 32 user user 4096 Jun  1 09:52 ..
drwx------  2 user user 4096 Jun  1 09:52 normal
$
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `grep -i gnome-shell /var/log/syslog*` (you'll have to paste that large output to paste.ubuntu.com).

Comment: Thanks for the data... however you forgot to notify me that you edited the question, and I almost missed the updates. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll surely miss future updates/comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gnome-shell is crashing all over the place. gnome-shell extensions are the probable cause.

The /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*gcampax.github.com extensions are suspect, and should be removed by using `Tweaks` or `Extensions` apps. Leave the following alone...

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 22 08:29 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Nov 19  2020 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Nov 19  2020 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Open the gsconnect settings and tell me the version number.

Monitor syslog to see if errors continue, using...

```
grep -i gnome-shell /var/log/syslog*
```

Comment: gsconnect I have already disabled/removed (along with system-monitor) so I am unable to tell you the version number - I assume since gnome-shell updates my extensions daily that it was the most recent stable though. sorry.

Comment: I removed the /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*gcampax.github.com extensions by running **sudo apt remove gnome-shell-extensions** and then ran a **sudo apt autoremove** for good measure (which removed gnome-shell-extension-prefs and libdazzle-1.0-0)

Comment: @Crusty to confirm that it's done correctly, do `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and confirm that the three extensions that I quote in my answer are still there. Also reinstall gnome-shell-extension-prefs and libdazzle-1.0-0. Keep monitoring to confirm if the gnome-shell errors are gone.

Comment: @Crusty If my answer helped to solve the gnome-shell errors, please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: where are you seeing the gnome-shell crashes? what is the log entry that indicates its crashing? I notice that I am down to just the default extensions but I still have 14 instances of the thumbnail error even after a fresh reboot, but I still don't know which thumbnail it is failing to load

Comment: @Crusty Look in your syslog posting starting at line 92.

Comment: @Crusty Do you have any themes or icon/font packs installed? Show me a screenshot of the upper-right corner of your screen.

Comment: @Crusty Log into a different user account and see if the problem shows up there.

Comment: @Crusty Show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: have updated post with requested information

Comment: @Crusty Sounds like you may have fixed it!

Comment: Not sure this answer answered my original question or was exactly what fixed my issues (maybe I had a corrupt image on my desktop or something) but it definitely provided useful debugging steps that were relevant in isolating a solution. Marking as Best Answer.